# How to set cookies jwt access token and refresh token in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm newbie to work with reactjs. i'm using djnago restframework for backend and reactjs for frontend. **I'm using cookies to store JWT token in reactjs** but i **don't know to set cookie with access token and refresh token**.

i need to use refresh token because my application user need to auto login without username password for 7 days with securely. But access token expires shortly.

**> And also i need suggestion for auto refresh token to work in reactjs**